# MATLAB create monthly timeseries from annual data

Tags: matlab, time, series

Hello I am trying to explore some annual data and it would be convenient to explore them every month. In order to separate the data I used this code for January:

```
d1 = '2021-01-01 00:00:00';
d2 = '2021-01-31 23:59:00';
t1 = datetime(d1,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
t2 = datetime(d2,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
idx_time = (date_time >= t1) & (date_time <= t2);
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the [`month`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.month.html) method to extract the month component from `date_time`, like this:

```
idx_time = month(date_time) == 1;
```

To create separate arrays for each month of data, you can use `findgroups` and `splitapply`, like this.

```
[g, id] = findgroups(month(date_time));
dataByMonth = splitapply(@(x) {x}, var, g)
```

This results in `dataByMonth` being a 12x1 `cell` array where each element is a single month of data. `id` tells you which month.

EDIT following discussions in the chat, it turns out that the following approach was what was needed.

```
l = load('data.mat');
% Create a timetable
tt = timetable(l.date_time, l.var);
% Aggregate per day
amountPerDay = retime(tt, 'daily', 'sum')
% Select days with non-zero amount
anyPerDay = timetable(rainPerDay.Time, double(amountPerDay.Var1 > 0))
% Compute the number of days per month with non-zero amount
retime(anyPerDay, 'monthly', 'sum')
```

(Note the use of `double(amountPerDay.Var1>0)` is to work around a limitation in older versions of MATLAB that do not permit `retime` to aggregate `logical` data)

EDIT 2:
To get the `Time` variable of the resulting `timetable` to display as a long month name, you can simply set [the `Format` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-display-format-of-date-and-time-arrays.html) of that variable:

```
rainyDaysPerMonth = retime(rainyDays, 'monthly', 'sum')
rainyDaysPerMonth.Time.Format = 'MMMM'
```

EDIT 3:
To get the rainiest day per month, this needs `splitapply` and a small helper function. Like this

```
g = findgroups(month(amountPerDay.Time));
% Use splitapply to find the day with the maximum amount. Also
% need to return the day on which that occurred, so we need a small
% helper function
rainiestDayPerMonth = splitapply(@iMaxAndLoc, amountPerDay.Time, ...
    amountPerDay.Var1, g);

% Given vectors of time and value, return a single-row table
% with the time at which the max value occurs, and that max value
function out = iMaxAndLoc(t, v)
[maxV, idx] = max(v);
out = table(t(idx), maxV, 'VariableNames', {'Time', 'Value'});
end
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "twelve monthly doubles"? You might be interested in the "Split Apply Combine" pattern https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html#buxwasl . Here, you could use `findgroups(month(date_time))` to group by months.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `timetable` data type. There are lots of tools for dealing with time-based data there. Including this sort of thing https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/computebygroup.html

Comment: Ok works. And now can I use the cell2mat command to make them monthly matrices?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `cell2mat` will stick the data back together into one big matrix. You can simply use `dataByMonth{4}` etc. to get each month's data. Or do you want separate variables, one for each month? (I would not recommend that...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249587/discussion-between-edric-and-mathew81).

Comment: In the 12X1 datetime (ans) can i replace the names of the first collumn to be Only January, February etc? Because now they are 01-01-2019, 01-02-2019 etc

Comment: Set the `Format` property. I edited the answer to include this. (Really you should have asked a new question for this...)

Comment: By default the tt = timetable(l.date_time, l.var); has the date_time collumn only with dates. How can also the time (HH:mm:ss) appear?

Comment: `tt.Time.Format = "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:SS"`. See the doc link I added to the answer describing the `Format` property.

Comment: I was mistaken with tt, date_time.Format = "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:SS" worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Using retime(tt, 'monthly', 'max'); in order to find in which day every month i have the max value, i get 01-01, then 01-02...01-12. Do you know why?

Comment: For that you need to go back to `splitapply`, not `retime`. `retime` always creates a `timetable` with a regular time interval, which is not what you want. I'm going to add yet another answer in here, but once again you really should have asked a new question...

Comment: rainiestDayPerMonth gives me an error: 
"Error using splitapply (line 132). Applying the function 'iMaxAndLoc' to the 1st group of data generated the following error:
Undefined function 'iMaxAndLoc' for input arguments of type 'datetime'."

Comment: The function `iMaxAndLoc` needs to be either placed in a file called "iMaxAndLoc.m", or appended to the end of the script containing the rest of your program (e.g. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html#bvfsr6o )

Comment: rainiestDayPerMonth returns the day with the maximum variable value, but the hour is always 00:00:00. Do you know why? I need to indicate the exact hour also..

Comment: That's because it's based on a daily aggregate from the `retime(tt,'daily','sum')` piece. If you want the rainiest hour, retime `'hourly'`, and proceed from there. The same `findgroups` and `splitapply` calls should work for you.